# Remover rota anterior do Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Em uma aplicação com várias localizações, tenho um botão para chamada de uma rota entre dois pontos utilizando a função *setDirection*, conforme inserido abaixo.

Gostaria de um suporte para poder remover uma rota traçada anteriormente depois de clicado em um outro marcador.

```
// Funções de roteamento

var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function setDirection(destLat, destLng) {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ polylineOptions:{strokeColor:"#4a4a4a",strokeWeight:5}, suppressMarkers:true });
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var request = {
    origin: pos.lat + ',' + pos.lng,
    destination: destLat + ', ' + destLng,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
    console.log(request);
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
});

return false;
}
```

Abaixo inseri uma função que mostra o mapa, incluindo o trecho onde tem-se o botão para "Traçar a Rota"

```
 // Recarrega marcadores
 function reloadMarkers() {
 var center = map.getCenter();
 setMapOnAll(null);
 map.setCenter(center);


downloadUrl(findUrl, pos, function (data) {
    var xml = data;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

        var name = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var address = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("address")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var type = markers[i].getElementsByTagName("type")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lat")[0].firstChild.nodeValue),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lng")[0].firstChild.nodeValue));
        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address +
                '<br><a href="#" onclick="return setDirection(' + markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lat")[0].firstChild.nodeValue + ',' + markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lng")[0].firstChild.nodeValue + ');">Traçar Rota</a>';
        var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
        });
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
});
```

}

Este é o botão onde eu retorno a função 'setDirection()':

```
 <a href="#" onclick="return setDirection(' + markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lat")[0].firstChild.nodeValue + ',' + markers[i].getElementsByTagName("lng")[0].firstChild.nodeValue + ');">Traçar Rota</a>
```

Comment: Tem como passar o código inteiro para ir testando no JSFiddle ou algum outro site do genêro? Quero pegar a instanciação do mapa inclusive.

Comment: Use a função: `directionsDisplay.setMap(null);`

Comment: Olá @GiancarloAbelGiulian. Tem sim. Coloquei no JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/lucastaglia/82e4qLv8. Você pode ver online o funcionamento da aplicação em (http://ondedescarto.com.br). Não sei se será possível ver os locais de coleta dependendo da sua localização, pois foram determinados em uma distância de 100km à partir da localização do usuário.

Comment: O setMap(null) que o @Dian Carlos passou está correta, talvez você não tenha colocado no lugar correto. <br>
Tente desta forma: var directionsDisplay = null; var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); function setDirection(destLat, destLng) { if(directionsDisplay != null){ directionsDisplay.setMap(null); } Só alterei a parte do seu código que acho relevante, o resto fica igual